# Data handling in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, web

I'm in the process of programming a web application that gets data from an inverter to which a PV cell is attached. I read the data from a CSV file. Every 20 seconds, the CSV file gains a line that contains the data at the respective point in time (line contains the following data: timestamp, current performance, energy).

The CSV file is saved to a database when the application is started (when the index action is called in the controller). It's all working.

Since the database now contains data at 20s intervals, it is rapidly increasing in size. Since I use graphs to show the energy that the PV system supplies me over the year on my web application, I have to summarize the 20s data, which also requires computing power. I also do this in the index action.

So whenever the user opens the page, the data is updated. If I e.g. switch from one view to the other and back again, the index action is called again in the associated controller. So it takes time to load the page again. So my application becomes slow.

What do I need to do to solve such a problem?

Comment: Does the device createa  csv by month, or does it just keep writing to one big file? At that rate, one year will be a csv file with 1.5 million rows. at say 30 characters per  hour, that is about 60 megs per year. Does the csv file really just keep growing? When does it get dumped, or say that the csv file name is change? (by month, by day by week??). I would doubt the csv file is for one whole year (might be), but additional information would help suggest a course of action here. Seems to me that a data file by 1 or even 10 minute intervals would be more then enough resolution here.

Comment: I only read the copy of an csv file, wich i delete when data is read. The new data gets on a new csv file.

Comment: Ok, so see my answer below, but in a nutshell, the approach would be to use what we call data warehousing concepts and ideas - thus reducing the amount of data by large amounts, and thus increasing the speed and ability to report on such data.

Comment: describe the `index action` which is - as you said in the last paragraph - called in the controller. also complete the question by adding these data: your table schema and indexes, your `SELECT` Query or ORM code you've used to retrieve data @Elias

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then.

In our IT industry, we often come across the term "data warehousing".

What this means (in most cases) is that we have a LOT of transaction data. Think maybe the very high transaction rate generated by people shopping on amazon. HUGE number of transactions.

But, if we want to report on such data? Say we want sales by hour, or maybe even only need by per day.

Well, we don't store each single transaction for that "house" of data, but a sum total, and a sum total over a given "chosen" time period by the developer of that data warehouse system.

So, you probably don't need to capture each 20 second data point. (maybe you do?????).

So, as I stated, every 20 seconds, you get a data point. Given a year has 31 million seconds? then that means you will have 1.5 million data points per year.

However, perhaps you don't need such fine resolution. If you take the data, and sum by say 1 minute intervals, then you now down to only 525,000 data points per year. (and if you report by month, then that is only 43,000 points per month).

However, maybe a resolution of 5 minutes is more then fine for your needs. at that resolution, then a whole year of data becomes only 105,120 data points.

And thus for a graph or display of one month of data, we have only 8,760 data points.

So, if we have to (for example) display a graph for one month, then we are only pulling 8,700 points of data. Not at all a large query for any database system these days.

So, you might want to think of this data as some "miniature" data warehousing project, in which you do loose some data "granularity", but as such, it still is sufficient for your reporting needs.

What time slot or "gap" you choose will be based on YOUR requirements or need.

What the above thus then suggests?

You would need a routine that reads the csv, and then groups the data by that "time slot" you chosen, and then sum into existing data points, and appends for the new ones.

This as a result would not only vast reduce the number of data rows of data, but of course would also significantly speed up reports and graphing on such data.

So, you could easy drop from about 1.5 million rows of data per year down to say 100,000 rows per year. With a index on the date, then reporting on such data be it daily, weekly, or monthly becomes far more manageable, and you reduced the data by a factor of 10x. Thus, you have a lot more headroom in the database, a lot less data, and after 10 years of data, you would only be around 1 million rows of data - not a lot for even the free "express" edition of SQL server.

Also, since you can't control when the "device" triggers adding of data to that csv, I would consider a re-name of the file before you read it, and thus during some read (and you deleting after done), you would reduce the possibility of losing data during your csv read + delete operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have one more question. Data from an inverter is written to the CSV file. One line contains the energy, power, timestamp, a value, for example whether an electric car is connected or not. The value of whether something is connected should be read out more often than the energy or power. Should I have this value written to a 2nd CSV file and then read it out more often? eg. this value every 15s?

Comment: Well it was never suggested by you that you have many options in what kind of csv file is produced here,  and that options like a ev being plugged in was to produce a separate csv file. But it's again up to you.  I can certainly think that connected ev time is valuable. So then is 1day total ev time sufficient or do you need/want ev time connected per hour? I would think by hour would be valuable since then graphically the ev plug in time would be nice- maybe even by 15 minutes.  So you have to sit down and figure out what you want.  Ev time could be written to separate table